# Icon in front of brand name in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am using twitter-bootstrap. I was wondering how you put an icon in front of the brand name.
Somehow the icon also seems like it is a lot smaler than the text. How can this be fixed so it looks good?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div class="container">
      <i class="icon-signal icon-white"></i>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Internett</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The icon widht/height doesn't change with the text, the images are a static 14px. Is that your issue?

Comment: The size is not really the issue. It's the placement. I want it dead center in front of the text an it is not. There is some code in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try including the icon inside the `.brand` title anchor and just align it with some css like so:

**CSS**

```
.brand i {
    margin-top: -4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Doesn't look pretty but it works.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/HGMdM/

Comment: This works. My brand name was still a little higher than it should be, so i added a .brand { margin-top: 2px; } and it's great now.

Comment: This bug still exists in bootstrap 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
margin:-4px
```

Example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i style="margin:-4px 0; color:pink" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i> <?= $config->siteName ?></a>
    </div>
      <p class="navbar-text"><i style="color:pink" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i> <?= $config->siteTagline ?></p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Inline used for demonstration. You can also inline `<style>` or add to your CSS file.

Issue reported to Bootstrap: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13100

Comment: Are you sure you want to use inline style?

Comment: Nope -- just for illustration.